# Core Data raises exception for fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My iOS app checks if an entity exists before performing save operations.

```
@implementation DataPrice


+ (NSString*)entityName
{
    return @"Price";
}


+ (instancetype)fetchDataPriceInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Price" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:YES];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = entity;
    request.sortDescriptors = @[ sortDescriptor ];
    request.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    DataPrice *result = fetchResults.firstObject;

    return result;
}
```

Running the code raises the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01497946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01120a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x004ce33e -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 5230
    3   DenkoStation                        0x000395d3 +[DataPrice fetchDataPriceInManagedObjectContext:] + 499
    4   DenkoStation                        0x00038ccb -[ViewController updateLocalPrice:] + 219
    5   DenkoStation                        0x000387a2 __52-[ViewController displayInternetConnectivityMessage]_block_invoke_3 + 1490
    6   DenkoStation                        0x000df531 __66-[RKObjectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke248 + 97
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0319b30a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x031bbe2f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x031a290e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 606
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x013f195e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x013b0760 __CFRunLoopRun + 2256
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x013afbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x013af9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x04fa824f GSEventRunModal + 192
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x04fa808c GSEventRun + 104
    16  UIKit                               0x01a5e8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    17  DenkoStation                        0x00039e0d main + 141
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x031e7ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

My guess is that Core Data is complaining because record `Price` doesn't exist.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: do you made changes in your coredata Price entity?

Comment: Try to clean and delete Previous app and install again

Comment: @johnykumar No I didn't. Logging `entity` returns null.

`NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Price" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"%@", entity);
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:YES];`

Comment: Try to clean and delete previous app from fone/simulator.

Comment: Reset Contents and Settings in the simulator, right?

Comment: either do reset content or delete app from simulator and install again

Comment: Have you checked that the managedObjectContext is correct? (i.e. at least not nil)

Comment: @Yaser `managedObjectContext` is initialized. I have checked. It's not `nil`.